# Multiple filters for Markers created using Google Fusion

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to create multiple filters for the markers based on columns in fusion tables. I want the filters to cross work in parallel and not individual filtering. Here is the code i have so far, i based it on an answer i found here by ERIC but it didn't work for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<style>
#map-canvas { width:500px; height:400px; }
  </style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="eq_jsonp.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">         </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var map;
 var layerl0;
var tableid = 3470746;
var locationCol = 'Latitude'; 
  function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.2798935535169, -81.3486099243164),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

 layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'latitude'",
      from: 3470746
    },
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function doQuery(){

// collect WHERE conditions here for each search-string value

 var query = [];

 var searchString = '';

// I'd name my select id's something more descriptive, e.g. "damage_level" vs search-     string1, etc.

 searchString = document.getElementById('classification').value;

 if(searchString){

 query.push(" 'Roadway Classification:' = '" + searchString + "'");

}

searchString = document.getElementById('name').value;

if(searchString){

query.push("'Roadway Name:' = '" + searchString + "'");

}

// Date Filter

 searchString = dateFilter();

if(searchString){

query.push(searchString);

}

// Now build the WHERE clause by joining with ' AND ' all the conditions.

// Note: if nothing is in the where Fusion Tables will not object

var where = query.join(' AND ');
//alert(where);

var qryOpts = {

query: {

  select: "'latitude'",

  from: 3470746,


  }

};

layer.setOptions(qryOpts);
return;

}

// set all form inputs to null and call doQuery again.

function resetQuery(){

 $('#classification').val('');
 $('#name').val('');
 doQuery();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 <form> 
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
   <label>Roadway Classification</label>
   <select id="classification" onchange="doQuery;" title="Select Roadway by  Classification">
    <option value="">--Roadway Type--</option>
    <option value="Collector">Collector</option>
    <option value="Highway">Highway</option>
    <option value="Minor Arterial">Minor Arterial</option>
  </select>
 </div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <label>Roadway Name</label>
  <select id="name" onchange="doQuery;" title="Select Roadway by Name">
    <option value="">--Roadway Name--</option>
    <option value="Neptune Rd">Neptune Rd</option>
    <option value="Partin Settlement Rd">Partin Settlement Rd</option>
    <option value="Shady Ln">Shady Ln</option>
   </select>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="doQuery();" value="Search" />

  <input type="button" onclick="resetQuery();" value="Reset" />
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a look at your [table 3470746](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=3470746) and your column names do not have colon's after them. Try:

```
query.push("'Roadway Name' = '" + searchString + "'");
```

and

```
query.push(" 'Roadway Classification' = '" + searchString + "'");
```

also you are not adding the where clause to your qryOpts:

```
var where = query.join(' AND ');


var qryOpts = {

query: {

  select: "'latitude'",

  from: 3470746,
  // WHERE clause was missing
  where: where

  }

};
```

Comment: Eric,thanks for your quick response. Good catch i have fixed the code according to your comment. However, still when i click "search" the filters do not work and the markers do not change accordingly. I am not sure where i went wrong!

Comment: Thanks Eric again, can u explain further what to write in the where clause? should it be where: 'Roadway Classification' AND 'Roadway Name' ?

Comment: I did some modifications to the table and the script where i removed spaces in the column names and i kept the column names in lower case. however, the search button still doesn't fire up correctly! what could be the issue?

Comment: No. It should be: 'Roadway Classification' = 'xxxxx' AND 'Roadway Name' = 'bbbbbb'

Comment: great, but since i have more than one option in each column it will be WHERE 'Roadway Classification'=('aaaa','bbbb','cccc') AND 'Roadway Name' = ('dddd','eeee','ffff') ?

Comment: I know i am asking many questions, i am sure i am so close but it's just not clicking right. I did the where clause as you said but seems like the function doQuery doesn't do what it should. Any hints will be appreicated

Comment: Not quite.  It should be 'Roadway Name' IN ('dddd','eeee', 'ffff') or another FT operater is CONTAINS so 'Roadway Name' CONTAINS ('Rd') would find all road named Rd vs. St

Comment: Eric you have been a great help, thanks i got the filters to work!my last issue is that the filters work individually, when for example two options in two filters are selected they kinda cancel each other out and all markers on map show. any input?

Comment: Well it's hard too tell w/o seeing any code.  Note: the FT API only supports AND queries, not OR.  But if that was the problem I'd expect no results vs. all results.  I'd expect all results when there's a syntax error in the query sent.